# SSRS How do I have 2 separate years worth of data as series groups in a graph?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am creating a dashboard on SSRS using text queries written in SQL.
The dataset I am using is grouping figures by the month of the year and we use a calendar table that holds details regarding calendar dates and series (Days of Year, Month Name, Year Month Name etc.) and this is used to group the figures by when working with the dataset.

What I am wanting to do is use 2 years (19/20 and 21/22) but completely miss out the full year 20/21 however I am not sure how to do this as a set of series groups inside SSRS.

If I just do 1 complete dataset then I can't break it down into series groups as it would just be 1 continuous line graph.

[Graph Example]

[image]

I have tried to pivot the dataset to work off months of the year but this wont work as then I cannot separate the years of data as as series and have the figures (number of attendances) inside.

In concept I would just need to add a new column to the existing query that looks at the current years data with '19/20' As the column name however I am not sure how to achieve this.

A example query would look like this;

```
 SELECT C.YearMonth   
   , COUNT(1) AS [Attendances]         
FROM xxx   
LEFT JOIN Calendar AS C ON xxx = xxx             
WHERE C.YearMonth BETWEEN '20190101' AND '20211231'   
GROUP BY C.YearMonth
```

What I need the output to look like is;

[Table Output Example *2020/21 should be 2021/22*]

[image]

Comment: why not simply remove all unwanted data with wHERE date not in what ever you don't need

Comment: @nbk as this would only create 1 long line graph starting from 20190101 up to 20211231 instead of only having 12 months on the x axis and having each years data as series groups.

Comment: no, when you have data from 01.01.2019 to 31.12.2022  and you remove 2020 and group by Month , year you get the  right data,

Comment: @nbk would I just do something like `WHERE YearMonth BETWEEN ('20190101' AND '20191231') OR YearMonth BETWEEN ('20200101' AND '20201231') GROUP BY CalendarYear` then pivot the table to use the months of the year?

Comment: The table exmaple does not reflect the what you said in the question. I assume the 2nd row should be `2021/22?` In any case, @nbk is correct (unless there is something we can't see). Just filter the data based on two ranges e.g. `WHERE (myDate between '2019-04-01' and '2020-03-31' OR myDate between '2021-04-01' and '2022-03-31')`

Comment: @AlanSchofield Apologies yes, it should have been 2021/22. The problem I had with this however is that if I do these date ranges, I get all the data I require in 1 long line graph but they aren't separated by the years as series groups which is where I am struggling. Would I need to group by the year instead and then pivot the table and use the Year month names as columns?

Comment: which dates exacly do you need 01.01.2019 till xx.yy.2020 and 01.01.2021 and xx.yy.2022 and so must be the where clause, so that every date that isn not in range is excluded

Comment: You'll need to add something to identify which Year it belongs in your dataset but you should not need to pivot the data, the chart will handle that as the X-Axis will be you Year/Month. You will need a column that will order the data for each year month e.g. `Year*100+Month` to give you `201904, 201905, ... 202003` etc.

Comment: Break your YearMonth into Year and Month. The Month would be the Category Group of the Chart and the Year would be the Series.

Comment: Problem with that is that it's a financial year April-March so it needs to have some indication of which 'year' it belongs to.  As the OP didn't state whether standard calendar months (01 = Jan etc) or financial (e.g. 01=April) months were being used, I thought the year+month column would fix that. really need to see some raw data to give a full answer though.

Answer (score 0):

The YearMonth would need to be offset by nine months to create the Financial Year field (if I read it correct, Apr '23 is the first 23/24). Then the report could be filtered by that field to select or exclude the FIN year.

The chart would have the Month as the Category and the FIN Year as the Series.

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR( DATEADD(MONTH, 9, CAST(YearMonth + '01' AS DATE))) - 1 AS CHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST(RIGHT(YEAR( DATEADD(MONTH, 9, CAST(YearMonth + '01' AS DATE))), 2) AS CHAR(2)) AS FIN_YEAR
    ,YearMonth
    ,RIGHT(YearMonth,2) R_Month
    ,LEFT(YearMonth, 4) C_Year
    ,COUNT(1) AS [Attendances]         
FROM xxx   
LEFT JOIN Calendar AS C ON xxx = xxx          
WHERE YearMonth BETWEEN '20220101' AND '20231231'   
GROUP BY CAST(YEAR( DATEADD(MONTH, 9, CAST(YearMonth + '01' AS DATE))) - 1 AS CHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST(LEFT(YEAR( DATEADD(MONTH, 9, CAST(YearMonth + '01' AS DATE))), 2) AS CHAR(2))
    , YearMonth
    ,RIGHT(YearMonth,2) 
    ,LEFT(YearMonth, 4)
ORDER BY YearMonth
```

[image]